# Invalid Webhook Token: code: 50027 after 15 minutes countdown

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I hope that someone can help me with this piece of code that I am brainstorming on and I am kinda fed up with it. After 15 minutes the console throws Invalid Webhook Token error after 15 minutes of countdown. The script edits an embed every minute and countsdown whatever timer is inserted by the Administrator e.g /lock lock-channel 2h 30m.

I did some research that the Discord API returns Error after 15 minutes because it's a slash command.

Can someone help me for a workaround how we can keep the timer running? It stops after 15 minutes
Any help would be much appreciated

**Edit: Fixed by using** `.editreply({` instead of `.reply()` and adding
`await interaction.deferReply()`

No more Wehhook Invalid Error

```
const { Permissions, ButtonBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  interaction: {
    name: "lock",
    description: "Locks/unlocks members from posting messages on the channel.",
    options: [
      {
        name: "lock-channel",
        description: "It restricts members from writing messages by locking the channel.",
        type: 1,
        options: [
          {
            name: "duration",
            description: "Duration for which to lock the channel (e.g., 2h 30m)",
            type: 3,
            required: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "unlock-channel",
        description: "Allows messages to be written to the channel by removing the lock.",
        type: 1,
        options: []
      },
    ]
  },
  interactionOnly: true,
  aliases: ["lock", "unlock", "kilit-aç", "kilitaç", "kanal-kilit", "kanalkilit", "kilitle"],
  category: "Moderation",
  memberPermissions: ["ManageChannels"],
  botPermissions: ["SendMessages", "EmbedLinks", "ManageChannels"],
  nsfw: false,
  cooldown: false,
  ownerOnly: false,

  async execute(client, interaction, data) {
    const getCommand = interaction.options.getSubcommand();
    const durationOption = interaction.options.getString('duration');
     
    // Get details of the user who used the command
    const userTag = interaction.user.tag;
    const userId = interaction.user.id;

    // Get details of the guild where the command was used
    const guildName = interaction.guild.name;
    const guildId = interaction.guild.id;

    console.log(`Admin ${userTag} (${userId}) used the command '${getCommand}' on server ${guildName} (${guildId})`);

    const destekSunucusuButton = new ButtonBuilder().setLabel('Support Server').setURL("https://discord.gg/VcYZc8G4js").setStyle('Link');

    try {
      if (getCommand == "lock-channel") {
        if (!durationOption) {
          return interaction.reply({
            embeds: [{
              color: client.settings.embedColors.red,
              title: "Error",
              description: "You need to specify the duration for which to lock the channel (e.g., `/lock 2h 30m`)."
            }]
          });
        }

        // Parse the duration provided by the admin
        const durationMatch = durationOption.match(/(\d+)([hm])/);
        if (!durationMatch) {
          return interaction.reply({
            embeds: [{
              color: client.settings.embedColors.red,
              title: "Error",
              description: "Invalid duration format. Please use a valid format such as '1h' for 1 hour or '30m' for 30 minutes."
            }]
          });
        }

        const [, amount, unit] = durationMatch;
        let lockDuration = parseInt(amount);

`        // Convert the duration to milliseconds based on the unit
        if (unit === 'm') {
          lockDuration *= 60 * 1000; // Convert minutes to milliseconds
        } else if (unit === 'h') {
          lockDuration *= 60 * 60 * 1000; // Convert hours to milliseconds
        } else {
          return interaction.reply({
            embeds: [{
              color: client.settings.embedColors.red,
              title: "Error",
              description: "Invalid duration unit. Please use 'h' for hours or 'm' for minutes."
            }]
          });
        }

        // Lock the channel
        await interaction.channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.guild.id, {
          SendMessages: false,
        });
        await interaction.channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(client.user.id, {
          SendMessages: true,
        });

        const lockMessage = await interaction.reply({
          embeds: [{
            color: client.settings.embedColors.green,
            title: `**»** ADVENTURERS, WE ARE CURRENTLY OUT OF CRATES. `,
            description: `Apologies for the inconvenience!`,
            fields: [
              {
                name: "Unlock Time",
                value: `This channel will be unlocked in ${formatDuration(lockDuration)}`,
                inline: true
              }
            ],
            image: {
              url: 'https://media1.tenor.com/m/La8Sp--h8WUAAAAC/restock-restocking.gif'
            }
          }]
        });`

`        // Schedule unlocking after the specified duration
        const unlockTimer = setInterval(async () => {
          lockDuration -= 60000; // Decrease the lock duration by 1 minute

          if (lockDuration <= 0) {
            // Unlock the channel
            clearInterval(unlockTimer);
            await interaction.channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.guild.id, {
              SendMessages: true,
            });

            // Send a message announcing the unlock
            await interaction.followUp({
              content: "@everyone",
              embeds: [{
                color: client.settings.embedColors.green,
                title: `**»** ADVENTURERS WE ARE BACK IN STOCK! `,
                description: `You're now free to spam **!crates** or **!chest**`,
                image: {
                  url: 'https://media1.tenor.com/m/RZfkVCgDz8EAAAAC/open-neon.gif'
                }
              }],
              components: [{
                type: 1,
                components: [destekSunucusuButton]
              }]
            });`

`            // Delete the lock message
            await lockMessage.delete();
          } else {
            // Update the lock message with the remaining time
            await lockMessage.edit({
              embeds: [{
                color: client.settings.embedColors.green,
                title: `**»** ADVENTURERS, WE ARE CURRENTLY OUT OF CRATES. `,
                description: `**Apologies for the inconvenience!**`,
                fields: [
                  {
                    name: "**Unlock Time**",
                    value: `# **This channel will be unlocked in:** ${formatDuration(lockDuration)}`,
                    inline: true
                  }
                ],
                image: {
                  url: 'https://media1.tenor.com/m/La8Sp--h8WUAAAAC/restock-restocking.gif'
                }
              }]
            });
          }
        }, 60000); // Update the lock message every minute
      } else if (getCommand == "unlock-channel") {
        // Unlock the channel immediately
        await interaction.channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.guild.id, {
          SendMessages: true,
        });

        await interaction.reply({
          content: "Channel has been unlocked by admin.",
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error handling interaction:', error);
      // Handle the error appropriately, such as sending a message or logging it
    }
  }
};`

`// Function to format duration in human-readable format
function formatDuration(duration) {
  const hours = Math.floor(duration / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const minutes = Math.floor((duration % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));

  let durationString = '';
  if (hours > 0) {
    durationString += `${hours} Hour${hours > 1 ? 's' : ''} `;
  }
  if (minutes > 0 || durationString === '') {
    durationString += `${minutes} Minute${minutes > 1 ? 's' : ''}`;
  }
  return durationString;
}`


I have tried everything to make it work, even `Catch-error` but unfortunately that did not work aswell

`DiscordAPIError[50027]: Invalid Webhook Token
    at handleErrors (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:722:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1120:23)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:953:14)
    at async _REST.request (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1266:22)
    at async InteractionWebhook.send (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Webhook.js:222:15)
    at async Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/container/commands/Moderation/Lock.js:134:13) {
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      content: '@everyone',
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: [Array],
      components: [Array],
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined,
      thread_name: undefined
    }
  },
  rawError: { message: 'Invalid Webhook Token', code: 50027 },
  code: 50027,
  status: 401,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/webhooks/681297139443302605/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTIxMTE0MDMxODM4MTIxOTg5MDppUllrek1EUUhaN3FETDZxNmpHWG1nbjNCbDVqT09hS01FMzMzMldTTmNoMkxCeUZieDRWZ1dZQjlHS2ZjVmtrNXF1MzB6b3FYSlAwczdicXFEdk0wQk9GSFppTTE5Ym5EYVpORkpWT0pRWkZrMUhLeWRTWmJabFBDMG1RVlhKRw?wait=true'
}
error.requestBody.json.embeds: [
  {
    color: 3066993,
    title: '**»** ADVENTURERS WE ARE BACK IN STOCK! ',
    description: "You're now free to spam **!crates** or **!chest**",
    image: {
      url: 'https://media1.tenor.com/m/RZfkVCgDz8EAAAAC/open-neon.gif'
    }
  }
]`
```

Answer (score -1):

**It's impossible to work(edit/send message, etc.) over 15min on one / command.**

*After the initial response, an interaction token is valid for 15 minutes, so this is the timeframe in which you can edit the response and send follow-up messages. You also cannot edit the ephemeral state of a message, so ensure that your first response sets this correctly.* [(discord.js guide)](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/response-methods.html#editing-responses)

To solve this,

1. make it work on text message

ex) if the command is `/lock`, than make it work by `!lock` message

2. use / command, but make it edit at other place (main file)

ex) when the command work, make it send and
save guild/channel/message id and other information at .json file.
Than, the main file reads the .json file and edits the `/lock` message

I hope you it helped you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).